# Is there a name for the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, terminology

Let $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ be the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{C}$.

This space $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ is called *the Riemann sphere*.

If I want to designate the topology $\tau$ on $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$, what shall I call it?

Is it ok to call it *the standard topology on $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$*?

For example, when I want to designate the usual topology on the extended real $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$, I write down *the order topology* or *the standard topology*. These names make no confusion. Is the situation same for the Riemann sphere?

Comment: The usual topology on $S^2$ is IMO well-known enough to use the word "standard".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already used the correct terminology: the "one-point compactification", which applies to any locally compact, noncompact Hausdorff space. That terminology refers both the union of $\mathbb{C}$ with one point $\infty$ and to the extension of the topology on $\mathbb{C}$ to a compact topology on $\hat{\mathbb{C}} = \mathbb{C} \cup \infty$.

Comment: "One-point compactification" designates a topological space or a process of the compactification. I want to know whether there is a word to designate **only** the topology on $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$. Would it be ok to call this topology as **The topology on $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$**?

Comment: As a small supplement one could note that after the one-point compactification of ${\mathbb C}$ to $\hat{\mathbb C}$ one can (and has to) *prove* that $\hat{\mathbb C}$ is in fact homeomorphic to the standard $2$-sphere $S^2$.

Comment: @Christian Yes I know that, but how that suggests a way to call **the topology** on $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$?

Comment: If you wish to refer to the topology alone, rather than to the set equipped with its topology, then for maximal clarity you could say "the one point compactification topology". If in what you are writing you say that just the first time, no-one will quibble if you then say something like ``from now on we call this just `the topology' on $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$''.